# Will `tune2fs -E stride=X` have the same effect as `mkfs.ext4 -E stride=X`

Tags: raid, software-raid, ext4

The `man tune2fs` and `man mkfs.ext4` state:

> stride=stride-size
>
> ...
>
> This mostly affects placement of filesystem metadata like bit‐maps at mke2fs(2) time to avoid placing them on a  single disk, 
>   which  can  hurt  the performance.

My question: Given an `ext4`-filesystem that was created without the `stride` option, will `tune2fs -E stride=X` have any effect on the placement of metadata as mentioned in the `man` pages?